# how i can write a query to get id from collection of doctor then i campre this id to current authentication user id

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();


                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            uid = user.getUid();

                            Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                    .child("Doctor").orderByKey().equalTo(uid);

                            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                                    {
                                        Extra_Table = "Doctor";
                                        finish();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(DoctorLogin.this,Profile.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(DoctorLogin.this,"Invalid Email For Doctor Login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                        }


                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(DoctorLogin.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                });
    }
```

i have three user doctor barber and beauty saloon ..  my problem is that when i put the email of doctor in  barbers login activity i can give the access because it can check email from authencition .. but i want i can only login when doctor email is given too doctor activity .. if other email is given to doctor login it does not give access to that user .. i am new i have running code for firebase database  ..but i want that same code for firestore .. if any body help me..??? thanks in advance

Comment: It can check email from authentication then what about the password?

Comment: the email and password it take from authentication table of firebase .. its not my problem  i nedd this query in firestore .. how i take the snapshot of id   Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                    .child("Doctor").orderByKey().equalTo(uid);

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: their is no any option for adding screen shot .. if you please tell me how i add the screen shot here..??